# Appending Array on top of Array to specified length

Tags: c#, arrays

I've made a function to append an array on top of itself to a specified length. The only issue I'm having is when the array is an odd number, say 9, and the length I'm trying to get it to, for example 20, it would output with 2 zeros at the end. I'm sure there's a way to have the array fill in every byte.

Current Function:

```
public static byte[] AppendToLen(byte[] input, int length)
{
    byte[] output = new byte[length];
    if (length <= input.Length) return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < length / input.Length; i++)
        Array.Copy(input, 0, output, input.Length * i, input.Length);
    return output;
}
```

Block of bytes

```
byte[] Block = new byte[0x10] { 0x02, 0x03, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x61, 0x37, 0x5f, 0xe8, 0x19, 0x70, 0xa2, 0x77, 0x8c, 0x94, 0x89, 0xb4 };
```

An example is:

```
foreach(byte bit in AppendToLen(Block, 56)) {
    Console.WriteLine(bit.ToString("X2"));
}

Ouput: 0203FF0461375FE81970A2778C9489B40203FF0461375FE81970A2778C9489B40203FF0461375FE81970A2778C9489B40000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example above you are only iterating twice because the `length / input.Length` term rounds down to 2. Remember that this is integer division. Also, remember not to walk off the end of your array. The snippet below does what you want.

```
    public static byte[] AppendToLen(byte[] input, int length)
    {
        byte[] output = new byte[length];
        if (length <= input.Length) return null;
        // Just use offset here since that's what you care about
        for (int offset = 0; offset < length; offset += input.Length)
            // Copy as much of the input array as possible to the output,
            // starting at this iteration's offset
            Array.Copy(input, 0, output, offset, Math.Min(length - offset, input.Length));
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not assigning any value to the remainder bytes. In your example 56 % 16 = 8, so you have 8 bytes left at the end after your loop without initialize. Now, the way you want to fill those I don't know, maybe with the first 8 bytes in your input array. If so, you would need to add an extra check after the loop to see if the remainder is > 0, and copy those 8 (remainder) bytes to the last positions of your array.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I could try using BlockCopy for the rest of it and see where that takes me.